# Problems with org.Hs.eg.db using clusterProfiler

Tags: r, bioinformatics, ontology, bioconductor

Does anyone know why this is not working? Something wrong calling the `org.Hs.eg.db`.

```
ego <- enrichGO(gene          = gene.df,
                universe      = names(geneList),
                OrgDb         = org.Hs.eg.db,
                ont           = "CC",
                pAdjustMethod = "BH",
                pvalueCutoff  = 0.01,
                qvalueCutoff  = 0.05,
                readable      = TRUE)

   > head(geneList)
          ENSEMBL ENTREZID   SYMBOL
1 ENSG00000000419     8813     DPM1
2 ENSG00000000457    57147    SCYL3
3 ENSG00000000460    55732 C1orf112
4 ENSG00000000971     3075      CFH
5 ENSG00000001036     2519    FUCA2
6 ENSG00000001084     2729     GCLC

> head(gene.df)
          ENSEMBL ENTREZID SYMBOL
1 ENSG00000100427    23209   MLC1
2 ENSG00000008517     9235   IL32
3 ENSG00000081237     5788  PTPRC
4 ENSG00000162645     2634   GBP2
5 ENSG00000000971     3075    CFH
6 ENSG00000115415     6772  STAT1

Error in enrichGO(gene = gene.df, universe = names(geneList), OrgDb = org.Hs.eg.db,  : 
  unused argument (OrgDb = org.Hs.eg.db)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was an old version of R in RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Try to direct to the entrez column of your data frame.

For example:

```
ego <- enrichGO(gene          = gene.df$ENTREZID,
                universe      = geneList$ENTREZID,
                OrgDb         = org.Hs.eg.db,
                ont           = "CC",
                pAdjustMethod = "BH",
                pvalueCutoff  = 0.01,
                qvalueCutoff  = 0.05,
                readable      = TRUE)
```